# How to query data from two tables where one table is populated and another is not (on laravel)

Tags: php

My tables are: media (id,media contents)
And  formtable (id,description, status)

Media is populated and formtable is not.
Now what i want is, when i retrieve data all data from the media table should appear and the black spaces from formtable should appear too.

Comment: What do you mean with `black spaces`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for is the use of a LEFT JOIN.  The Left Join will let you select data from a main/populate table and join it to a more sparce table, linking records that match by some select ID, but not prevent return of records from the main table that do not have a corresponding record in the other table

It might look like this

```
SELECT   
   u.user_id,
   u.user_name,
   u.account_type,
   u.email_addr,
   l.last_login,
   l.ip_address
From  User u
   LEFT JOIN Logins l  ON(u.user_id=l.user_id)    # or whatever key you want
```

This will return you all the 'Users'  regardless if they have ever logged in or not..  those records where they have not will return   NULL for  l.last_login and l.ip_address.

I hope this helps you.